# Схлопывание ячеек двух разных таблиц

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Собственно есть две таблицы, одна под другой, находятся в разных div'ах, но в одном контейнере.
Как можно реализовать "схлопывание" окна, чтобы соответствующие колонки таблиц оставались пропорциональных размеров?
В идеале чтобы первые ячейки в ширину были на хх% от ширины окна.

> http://tarasovych.ho.ua/page/ вопрос касается td.itogo.commontable и td.col_title.commontable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать jQuery.

```
function setWidth(){
var itogoWidth=$('td.itogo.commontable').css('width');
$('td.col_title.commontable').width(itogoWidth);
}
```

И вызывать эту функцию при каждом изменении таблицы или размера окна.

Comment: А без jQuery есть варианты?

Comment: На чистом js можно использовать     itogoWidth=document.getElementById("itogo").style.width и     document.getElementById("commontable").style.width = itogoWidth , но тогда придется по id их брать. Как по классу - не помню. Или вас интересуют варианты вообще без js ?

Comment: Да, вообще без js
Проблема в том что верхние td.col_numbers "двигаются не синхронно" с нижними когда размер окна меняется
http://i.imgur.com/ebf0CDq.png http://i.imgur.com/K0l8Q9G.png

Comment: Так разве как раз js не решает эту проблему? Отслеживаете движение и функция автоматически выровняет.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы вышеупомянутая функция вызывалась при изменении размера окна?

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){
  setWidth();
});

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44796/discussion-between-tarasovych-and--).